# Show that the series does not converge uniformly on the interval $I=(-r,0]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider the power series: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(n^2+3n+2)x^n.$$
**a)** Find the radius of convergence $r$ for the series.

**b)** Show that the series is the Taylor series for $f(x)=\frac{2}{(1+x)^3}$ in $x=0$.

**c)** Show that the series does not converge uniformly on the interval $I=(-r,0]$. (You can, without proof, use the fact that the series is convergent towards $f$ on the interval of convergence.)

**...In a) I've found the radius of convergence to be $r=1$. Can anybody help me with question c)?**

Comment: Well, by the ratio test:

$$\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\space\left|\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\text{n}+1}\cdot x^{\text{n}+1}\cdot\left(\left(\text{n}+1\right)^2+3\cdot\left(\text{n}+1\right)+2\right)}{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\cdot x^\text{n}\cdot\left(\text{n}^2+3\cdot\text{n}+2\right)}\right|=$$
$$\lim_{\text{n}\to\infty}\space\left|\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\text{n}+1}}{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}\cdot\frac{x^{\text{n}+1}}{x^\text{n}}\cdot\frac{\left(\text{n}+1\right)^2+3\cdot\left(\text{n}+1\right)+2}{\text{n}^2+3\cdot\text{n}+2}\right|=\left|x\right|\space<\space1\tag1$$

Comment: Why not writing this as an answer (-1).

Comment: @JanEerland How does this prove that the series is not uniformly convergent on $I$?

Answer (score 1):

To show that a serie is uniformly convergent, you generally show that

$$R_N(x) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty (-1)^n(n^2+3n+2)x^n \xrightarrow[{N\to\infty}]{} 0 \qquad \text{uniformly}$$

Namely, because for $x < 0$ the sum is always positive, if we note $R_N(x)$ this sum, that $\forall \epsilon, \exists N_0 > 0, \forall N > N_0, \forall x \in ]-1;0], R_N(x) \leq \epsilon$. But here we are going to show the opposite, namely, $\exists \epsilon, \forall N_0 > 0, \exists N > N_0, \exists x \in ]-1;0], R_N(x) > \epsilon$. which can be written $\exists \epsilon, \forall N > 0, \exists x \in ]-1;0], R_N(x) > \epsilon$. Any $\epsilon$ can work, so:

Fixing $A > 0$, no matter how big you choose $N$, you will always be able to find $x \in ]-1;0]$ such that it is bigger than $A$ (because it still tends to infinity). This shows the opposite of uniformly convergence, hence it is not uniformly convergent.

To show this:
Fix $\epsilon = 1$, $N > 0$. The function $x \mapsto R_N(x)$ is decreasing with $R_N(x) \xrightarrow[{x\to -1}]{} +\infty$. So, by definition we can find a $x$ such that $R_N(x) > \epsilon$.

And to show that $R_N(x) \xrightarrow[{x\to -1}]{} +\infty$, it is sufficient to show, that is not upper bounded (by monotonicity). If it was upper bounded by $K$. Then the sum from $N$ to $M$ would be upperd bounded by $K$ (for all $x$). So you make $x$ tend to $-1$ and then $M$ tend to infinity and you shouw that $R_N(-1) < +\infty$ which is not true.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the argument. What is it that tends to infinity?

Comment: To show uniform convegence, you have to show that the sum from $N$ to $\infty$ tends to $0$ uniformly when $N$ tends to $\infty$. Namely, because for $x < 0$ the sum is always positive, if we note $R_N(x)$ this sum, that $\forall \epsilon, \exists N_0 > 0, \forall N > N_0, \forall x \in ]-1;0], R_N(x) \leq \epsilon$. But here we show the opposite, namely, $\exists \epsilon, \forall N_0 > 0, \exists N > N_0, \exists x \in ]-1;0], R_N(x) > \epsilon$. which can be written $\exists \epsilon, \forall N > 0, \exists x \in ]-1;0], R_N(x) > \epsilon$. You can take any $\epsilon$, here I took $A > 0$.

Comment: Is it more clear?

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with your definition of uniform convergence. In my book there are the following two defintions: $$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\geq N,\forall x\in I: |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon,$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0.$$
Is it correct to say that your argument is this: For $x\in I$ the sum of the series tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity, hence it does not tend to $0$ and thus cannot be uniformly convergent on $I$ ?

Comment: The two definitions that you gave are equivalent, and the first one the one I used, just replace $f_n(x)$ by $R_N(x)$, as $R_N(x)$ tends to 0 for every x, you can replace $f(x)$ by $0$, and as $R_N(x)$ is positive you can remove the absolute value. Are you convinced? What you are saying is false, if you fix $x \in ]-1;0]$, then $R_N(x)$ tends to $0$. But not uniformly, which means you basically that if you take an $x$ closer to $-1$, you will have to take a bigger $N$ to show that $R_N(x) < \epsilon$, no $N$ will work for every $x$ in the interval. =

Comment: Alright, I think I understand the reasoning. I am, however, still unsure of how to make a formal proof of it. If, for instance, I let $\epsilon=0.1$ how do I prove that $R_N(x)>0.1,\forall N>0$ for some $x\in (-1,0]$?

Comment: I update the answer

Answer (score 0):

To simplify replace $x$ by $-x$; we have to show that the series $\sum (k^2+3k+2)x^k$ does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$. Suppose it do. For $\varepsilon=1$ , there exists an $N$ such that  we have for all $n\geq N$ $\sum_{k\geq n}(k^2+3k+2)x^k<\varepsilon=1$ for every $x\in  [0,1[$,. Let $m\geq n\geq N$. As all the factors are $\geq 0$, we have that $P(x)=\sum_{m\geq k\geq n}(k^2+3k+2)x^k \leq \sum_{k\geq n}(k^2+3k+2)x^k<1$ for $x\in [0,1[$. By continuity of this polynomial, this imply that $\sum_{m\geq k\geq n}(k^2+3k+2)\leq 1$ for all $m\geq n\geq N$. This imply the convergence of the series $n^2+3n+2$, obviously a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

For the question c : it's simple , you see it's an alternating series, meaning it's something-something+something-something+something ....
I'll call $U_n=(-1)^n(n^2+3n+2)x^n$
In order for the series to converge as an alternating series,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\rvert<1$$
As well as having $\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n=0$

Let's first evaluate $\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}$ :
$$\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}((n+1)^2+3(n+1)+2)x^{n+1}}{(-1)^n(n^2+3n+2)x^n}=-x\times\frac{n^2+5n+6}{n^2+3n+2}$$
And so :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}=-x\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+5n+6}{n^2+3n+2}$$

we see that in the second limit the highest powers are 2, and the coefficients of both are equal to $1$ so the limit is equal :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}=-x$$
since $x\in(-1,0]$, then $0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}<1$ And so the first test is aqcuired and returned with success. The second tests now consits of proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n=0$ so let's do that :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n(n²+3n+2)x^n$$
We have $x^n$ an exponential function thus we treat it first. We know that $x\in(-1,0]$ so $x^n$ is a decreasing function meaning that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$ and so $\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n=0$ and the second test is passed.
That means that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n²+3n+2)x^n$ for $I=(-r,0]$ converges.

I hope that helped, it's called the Alternating series test.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, I already know from a) that the series is convergent on (-1,1). What I am asked to show in c) is that the series is not uniformly convergent on $(-1,0]$.

Comment: Oh well, sorry for that then

Comment: "In order for the series to converge as an alternating series,
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lvert\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\rvert<1$" This is wrong, it may happen that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lvert\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\rvert=1$ and that the series converges.